# I could not get different videoplayers for different cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to play video on many of the cells of my table view.

My movie player object is not new for every cell.

But I can not play the different video for different cells, same video is played for all cells. It hink because of reusing property of the cell, player var is also reused.

I put a condition player==nil then alloc condition in cell.m file, but it is not working.

Only one time I can alloc the cell, afterwords It does not go in condiotns.

**here player also reused with cell. That Id od ot want I want to be hold that player with the cell.**

But things does not come, which condition should I put or which property I shopuld use in cell.m file.

**cell.m file coding**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;


       NSURL *videoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[cell.searchDict objectForKey:@"image_path1"]];
                //            if(player!=nil && [[player.contentURL absoluteString] isEqualToString:videoURL.absoluteString]){
                //                [player.view removeFromSuperview];
                //                player=nil;
                //
                //            }


                // if(cell.player==nil){
                [cell.player.view removeFromSuperview];
                cell.player=nil;

                cell.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

                cell.player.view.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH-14, 407.0);
                cell.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
                cell.player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
                cell.player.allowsAirPlay = NO;
                cell.player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                cell.player.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                cell.player.shouldAutoplay = YES;

                //                self.player.
                cell.player.view.tag=indexPath.row;
                [cell.viewForImage insertSubview:cell.player.view aboveSubview:cell.card_showimg];

//                [[cell.player.view layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
//                [[cell.player.view layer] setBorderWidth:3.0f];


                //   }


                cell._loadNotification = MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification;
                if ([cell.player respondsToSelector:@selector(readyForDisplay)]) {
                    // iOS 6, listen for this notification instead
                    cell._loadNotification = MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification;
                }

                // tell us when the video has finished playing
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(splashPlaybackStateDidChange:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                           object:cell.player];


                //        cell.player.view.hidden = FALSE;
                //        cell.backgroundImageView.hidden = FALSE;

                //        [_player setContentURL:url];
                [cell.player prepareToPlay];

                [cell.player play];


            }
            else{


                [cell.player.view removeFromSuperview];
                cell.player=nil;
            }

        }
        else{


            [cell.player.view removeFromSuperview];
            cell.player=nil;
        }
```

I am using this coding for reusing cells.

```
ExploreVCCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OfferCell"];
```

Comment: where you have written player code?

Comment: In my cell.m file.

Comment: ok...but how one player can play video with different URL at a time?

Comment: No no no for each cell I want different videos, So I want new video player for different cells.

Comment: How do you send the URL to the cell and are you sure it is always a different URL?  Please share all your code inside `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`.

Comment: Yes it is always different URL. I have written all code in cell.m file. I am sharing the code.

Comment: The line `NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [cell.searchDict objectForKey: @"image_path1"]]` seems to be getting the same URL everytime. What is "searchDict" ? And, please share your code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: No it is diffeent, I have checked it.

Comment: It is still not clear how you are setting up your cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. And you wrote that the code you posted in is Cell.m? Then why are you calling `cell.player`, etc; that should be `self.player`?    Please share more code (properly formatted), for us to be able to understand what is going on.